# Cyclomatic complexity and basis path

Tags: unit-testing, testing

Lets, consider we have the following method:

```
public void testIt(boolean a, boolean b){
   if (a && b){
   ...
   }
   if (a){
   ....
   }
}
```

Cyclomatic complexity of this method =3. So, according to basis path testing we should have 3 tests in order to achieve statement and decision coverage.
However, I see that I can use only two tests (true, true) and (false,false) to achieve statement and decision coverage. Where is my mistake?

Comment: Actually unless the first condition contains a return statement the Cyclomatic complexity is 1; (true, true). Does the second condition is 'If-Else'? If so the Cyclomatic complexity is 2; (true, true), (true, false)...

Comment: @Old Fox The second condition is not if else. There is no if else in the code.

Comment: My fault... I read again your question and post an answer... You've asked a good question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

answer from @OldFox is correct, just some additions:

> > Where is my mistake?

CC is upper bound for branch coverage, but it is lower bound for paths coverage (not the same as line/statement coverage, see below). So you need **up to 3** tests to cover all branches/conditions and **at least 3 tests** to cover all paths.

Here is the graph of your function:

[image: CFG]

CC = 6 - 5 + 1*2 = **3** according to [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity#Definition)

To cover all branches you need up to 3 tests, and actually you need all 3 to cover (true, true), (true, false), and (false, *)

To cover all paths you need at least 3 tests, there are 3 possible independent paths in graph, so you need only 3 tests to cover all paths.

There could be some confusion about number of different inputs, which is 4, but not all paths formed by these inputs are independent, two of them (when a is false) are actually the same, so there are only **3 independent paths**

conclusion, 3 test cases are necessary and sufficient to provide both branch and paths coverage for your function.

now about line/statement coverage: you need to execute every line at least ones, to achieve this you need only one test (true, true), but clearly it is not enough for other types of coverage.

Comment: To cover all branches I need 3 or 2 tests?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you are right. The Cyclomatic complexity is 3 and the cases you should verify are:

1. a is false, b - we don't care (I explain later...) -> nothing happened
2. a is true, b is false -> only the second condition was executed
3. a and b are true -> both the first and the second conditions were executed

If you look only through the arguments the first option I mentioned has 2 different inputs(b true/false), however in both cases the same should happen, so I offer you to verify it only once or to use the equivalent to [C# test case attribute](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=testCase&r=2.5)

Comment: I don't understand the logic. You say about three variants - or nothing, or both, or only the second conditions. However, then why there is not variant where only the first condition?

Comment: @JimJim2000 Based on the code you published, the variant where the only the first condition will execute is not exist.

Comment: No, there is no logic. Suppose the code of the same method `if(a){...} if (b){...}`. CC=3. Number of tests?

Comment: @JimJim2000 can you elaborate your last comment... I don't understand your intention...

Comment: I mean analyse this code: `if(a){...} if (b){...}`. CC=3. So what tests will you do (method signature is the same)?

Comment: @JimJim2000 In this case the CC is 4([Nice YouTube video about measuring CC](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wM2Cb-1XY-Y))  and you have 4 different test cases to do.

Comment: No, CC=3. Calculate if's and add one. Or you can calculate regions {} and add one.